# Typescript: import class from local module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two separate files. These compile using grunt and create two separate .js files. I want to be able to call printBar() in the readBar() function. The code itself is vastly more complex, I am just trying to address a ticket for functionality.

file a store in MyFolder/src/Foo.ts

```
module Test1Module {
    export class Foo {
        public readBar() {
            // ToDo:: Figure out how to call printBar()
        }
    }
}
```

file b stored in MyFolder/jquerysrc/Bar.ts

```
module Test2Module {
    export class Bar {
        public printBar() {
            console.log("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of MyFolder/jquerysrc there is a references.ts file. I see inside of it:

```
/// <reference path = "Bar.ts" />
```

In my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
}
```

I tried importing Test2Module at the top of the Foo.ts, using

```
import Bar from "../jquerysrc/Bar";
import Bar1 = require("../jquerysrc/Bar");
```

which gave me an error Cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations.

I also tried in the Foo class

```
var tmp = Test2Module.Bar; // which looked like it was able to be found (showed namespace + class in VScode)
```

But then it gave me a 'Cannot Find Namespace Test2Module' in the console trying to build

How do I call the `printBar()` function from `Bar.ts` in `Foo.ts` ?

Comment: `module` keyword has been renamed to `namespace`?

Comment: @Joel in code I see it as Module. Using VSCode to hover over the element it says namespace and using grunt deploy it shows a 'Cannot Find Namespace ... '. In the grunt deploy it looks like tsc v1.8.10